# I getting a error in flutter doctor cmd tools in ubuntu 21.04

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-doctor

I getting the following error in flutter doctor cmd tools, when I run the command `flutter doctor` in the terminal in ubuntu 21.04.

[image]

[cmd Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7Cz2.png)

I tried to solve in ubuntu but my try is waste next what can I do
Help Me guys.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is to open Android Studio and go to SDK Manager, switch to the SDK Tools tab.
[image]
Check Android SDK Command-line Tools(latest)
[image]
Don't forget to add to your PATH the tools and platform-tools folder that is inside your SDK.

Run flutter doctor to verify. You can also restart the Android studio.

This should solve your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is written on the Command.

For **cmdline-tools component is missing**  Run this command on your terminal

```
your_path_to_sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"
```

And for **Android license status unknown** Run this command on your terminal

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

and then accept the changes.

After successfully running this commands rerun the **flutter doctor** command.